# Can objects destroy themselves? (Java)

Tags: java, garbage-collection

We all know that the JRE will destroy any object that can no longer be referenced. But is there a way for an object to explicitly destroy itself? Or is that forbidden to avoid the dangling pointer problem?

Naively, I would like to say `this = null`, but that is disallowed by the compiler (`this` is probably not a true variable anyway).

Conversely, is there a way for an object to forcibly keep itself alive, by maintaining private copies of `this`, or otherwise?

Comment: I was enlightened yesterday when I realised the purpose of the file hard-link in Unix and its analogy with garbage collection systems.

Comment: Is this an academic question, or is there an actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @MДΓΓ БДLL for the moment, it's purely academic. I can, however, think of situations where you would want to ensure that objects in memory have been properly destroyed.

Comment: you are right, objects can not destroy themselves. you can set their *reference* to null, so gc will pick them, but not inside the object itself. Nor can it keep itself alive - you can dump it into a static collection/ reference but not otherwise.

Comment: Are you trying to make an object garbage-collect itself? I think that should not be a purpose of an object in an application (specially in Java).

Comment: Use-after-free is considered bad. What would destroying an object mean anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ignoring the academic aspect, you can't ensure an object is physically destroyed in Java (or most any other garbage collected language, like C#). This is because destroying objects is expensive (partly because of the memory compression phase), so the point is to run it as few times as possible.

This said however, you *can* force an object to release its allocated resources using the disposable pattern, where the object in question exposes a public method to release resources, and you can call it at any time (or it gets called automatically in the finalizer). It requires a bit more bookkeeping, but it gets the job done if really needed.

Answer (score 4):

No.  In fact, you cannot forcibly destroy *anything*.  Even if you have no references to an object, it will continue to exist in memory until the garbage collector decides to run and collect it.

You could keep an object alive by keeping a static reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

No you can't destroy an object.

What you could do is have a wrapper object that holds the actual object. If you make sure that nobody else has a reference to that object removing the reference (e.g. by setting it to null) will make the object qualify for the garbage collector. Note that it is still up to the GC to decide when and if to actually collect the garbage.

In order to keep an object alive you need to make sure that there is a reference to it. One way would be to have a static reference from the class of the object. As long as nobody unloads the class your object will stay in memory.

Answer (score 0):

As you said I think it is forbidden to avoid dangling pointer problems. Java memory model is based on Stack and Heap model, if an object destroys itself then what would go to stack (or) other pointers, which references the object?